# How can I calculate the RMS value?

Tags: ac

What will be the RMS value of a sawtooth waveform?

I am using this to calculate the ripple factor in a full wave rectifier circuit with a capacitor filter.

Comment: It will be the same as it is for a triangle wave. Might I suggest that you try and work this out yourself (given that it sounds like homework) and, that you try to listen to comments I've made on your earlier questions.

Comment: [This might help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/483027/rms-current-average-current-questions/483055#483055)

Comment: Hopefully you know calculus, so all it takes is doing an integral over one period of the sawtooth, using the definition of RMS voltage.

Comment: Arinjoy, Thanks for providing the question's motivation. In the case of a full wave rectifier with capacitor filter, it's not easy to predict the exact shape (everything matters, including any load or lack of same) of the output the load sees. Using the mathematical definition of the RMS value of anything assumes you know the shape over a cycle. In a practical system, the calculation is possible but difficult (diode drop continuously varies.) Is this an idealized system where you can make a lot of assumptions?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the general formula for the RMS-voltage is given by:

$$\text{V}_\text{RMS}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\text{T}}\int\limits_0^\text{T}\left(\text{V}\left(t\right)\right)^2\space\text{d}t}\tag1$$

Where \$\text{T}\$ is the period of the function.